# I am getting value date1 and date2 but only shows 0 value

Tags: php

I want to get monthly report between two values date1 and date2 display o value always

> table name "fuel_transaction"
>   field ="locoopbalance" store all values

**php code here**

```
<?php                        
    $querya =  $this->db->where('issuedate >=',$date1);
    $querya = $this->db->where('issuedate <=',$date2);
    $querya = $this->db->where('locoopbalance');
    $querya = $this->db->get('fuel_transaction'); 
        if ($querya->num_rows() > 0)
            {
            foreach ($querya->result() as $rowa)
                {
                $opbalance+= $rowa->locoopbalance;
                }
            }
            echo $opbalance+0;      
    ?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here. $this->db->where('locoopbalance'); ?

Comment: This `$querya = $this->db->where('locoopbalance');` makes no sense

Comment: "locoopbalance" table field name

Comment: what is `$this->db`? Are you using any `ORM`? if yes, which one?

Comment: display value table colomn name "locoopbalance"

Comment: @AakashTushar looks like CodeIgnitor

Comment: Try this to select $this->db->select('locoopbalance')

Comment: looks like Codeigniter has this ~> `$this->db->get_where('table_name', ['column_name' => 'value_to_match'], $limit, $offset);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_column along with array_sum,

```
$querya = $this->db->select('locoopbalance'); // should be select. not where
$querya = $this->db->get('fuel_transaction');
if ($querya->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result    = $querya->result_array();
    $opbalance = array_sum(array_column($result, 'locoopbalance'));
}
echo $opbalance + 0;
```

Solution 2:

```
$this->db->select_sum('locoopbalance');
$this->db->from("fuel_transaction");
$this->db->where('issuedate >=', $date1);
$this->db->where('issuedate <=', $date2);
$querya = $this->db->get();
echo $querya->row()->locoopbalance;
```